# Which quantity is greater, $\frac{x^2}{y+\frac1y}$ or $\frac{y^2}{x+\frac1x}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

$x \gt y$, $ xy \neq 0$

A= $ x^2\over {y+{1\over y}}$

B= $ y^2\over {x+{1\over x}}$

Options:

1) Quantity A is greater.

2) Quantity B is greater.

3) The two quantities are equal.

4) The relationship cannot be determined from the given information.

By taking $x=2, y=1 $, I get $A\gt B$ , Thus options 2 and 3 are eliminated.

By taking$ x=2, y=-1$ , I get $B\gt A$ , Thus option 1 is eliminated.

So answer is option 4.

But I am not satisfied with this solution by taking particular values of $x$ and $y$.

Is there any other method to deal with this question?

What should be proper tag for this?
I think it should be comparision but that is not available in tag list.So please edit it.

Comment: This looks like a general GRE question. While you may not be content with the rigorousness of your approach, this is exactly the type of quick-and-dirty steps to eliminate answers which you're expected to take under the given time constraints. That said, the alternatives provided so far in the answers are excellent for obtaining a more complete understanding of the posed problem.

Comment: Disproving via explicit counterexample is the way to go.  Don't feel you have to fill a page with derivational mumbojumbo just to be "mathematical".

Comment: create a tag if one is not present

Answer (score 9):

Suppose I compute the difference $A-B$ and see if it is always of one sign.
$$\begin{align}A - B &=\frac{x^2}{y+1/y} - \frac{y^2}{x+1/x}\\
&=\frac{yx^2}{y^2+1} - \frac{xy^2}{x^2+1}\\
&=\frac{xy\left(x(x^2+1)-y(y^2+1)\right)}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}\\
&=\frac{xy(x-y)(x^2+xy+y^2+1)}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}\\
&=\frac{xy(x-y)\left((x+y/2)^2+3y^2/4+1\right)}{(x^2+1)(y^2+1)}\end{align}$$

Every term in the last expression is positive but the term $xy.$ Therefore $$A > B \text{ if and only if } xy > 0.$$

Answer (score 8):

If D really is the true answer, then supplying counterexamples to every other claim is the only way to prove it. And there is no shame in doing it that way.

Comment: Supplying counterexamples (or proving the existence of such) is not only *the easiest way* to prove that D is the answer, it is *the only way* to prove that D is the answer.  Often, the most efficient approach is an educated guess.

Comment: D is basically saying "there are counterexamples to all of A,B,C" so it's no surprise there is no other way.

Answer (score 3):

A nice approach is as follows: note first of all that $x + 1/x$ is positive if $x$ is positive and negative if $x$ is negative. Now, if $x$ and $y$ have the same sign, then
$$
A > B \iff\\
\frac{x^2}{y+1/y} > \frac{y^2}{x+1/x} \iff \\
x^2(x + 1/x) > y^2(y + 1/y) \iff \\
x^3 + x > y^3 + y
$$
Note, however, that $f(x) = x^3 + x$ is an increasing function.  So, $x^3 + x > y^3 + y \iff x > y$.  So, $A > B \iff x > y$

On the other hand, if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs, then
$$
A > B \iff\\
\frac{x^2}{y+1/y} > \frac{y^2}{x+1/x} \iff \\
x^2(x + 1/x) < y^2(y + 1/y) \iff \\
x^3 + x < y^3 + y \iff\\
x < y
$$
So, it suffices to take any positive values $x<y$, then the values $-x,y$.

Answer (score 2):

Informally, I think you should be able see that as $x$ and $y$ both increase towards positive infinity, A is larger. As $x$ and $y$ both approach negative infinity, A is smaller.

You can show this by letting $(x, y)>0$, and $x = ay$ for $a > 1$. Then the opposite for the negative side